# Causing Uncaught Syntax error when clicking the dropdown list in navbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Currently, I got an error when I click the dropdown list in my website. Error is `Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #`. That error only cause when I use my website in Chrome or Edge. Currently, I'm using in IE11 and it cause no error for me but IE11 is shutting down, so I'm migrating to Chrome and I found that error. Is there any way to fix it?

```
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li class='dropdown'>"; //site
    echo "<label id='sit' class='dropbtn' value=''>CHOOSE SITE</label>";
        echo "<div class='dropdown-content'>";
        echo "<label class='content' value='sit_0'>ALL</label>";
      echo "<label class='content' value='sit_7'>AMK6E</label>";
        echo "<label class='content' value='sit_4'>AMKJ9</label>";
        echo "<label class='content' value='sit_9'>TPY</label>";
    echo "</div>";
echo "</li>";
echo "<li class='dropdown'>"; //year
    echo "<label id='yea' class='dropbtn' value=''>CHOOSE YEAR</label>";
        echo "<div id='year' class='dropdown-content'>";
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(`yearweek`, 4) AS 'year' FROM `$tbl` WHERE LEFT(`yearweek`, 4) >= '2015' ORDER By `year` ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {     
            echo "<label class='content' value='yea_".$row["year"]."'>".$row["year"]."</label>";
        }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    echo "</div>";
echo "</li>";
echo "<li class='dropdown'>"; //platform
    echo "<label id='pla' class='dropbtn'>CHOOSE PLATFORM</label>";
    echo "<div id='platform' class='dropdown-content'>";
    echo "</div>";
echo "</li>";
echo "<li class='dropdown'>"; //start week
    echo "<label id='str' class='dropbtn'>CHOOSE START WEEK</label>";
    echo "<div id='strweek' class='dropdown-content'>";
    echo "</div>";
echo "</li>";
echo "<li class='dropdown'>"; //end week
    echo "<label id='end' class='dropbtn'>CHOOSE END WEEK</label>";
    echo "<div id='endweek' class='dropdown-content'>";
    echo "</div>";
echo "</li>";
echo "<li class='dropdown'>"; //end week
  echo "<label id='run' class='dropbtn'>RUN</label>";
echo "</li>";

echo "</ul>";
```

---

> Below is Javascript code.

---

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.content').click(function(){
        var raw = $(this).val(); 
        var sid = raw.substring(0,3);
        var val = raw.substring(4,raw.length);
        
        //alert('rep value: '+$('#rep').val());
        //alert(sid+" - "+val+": "+$(this).text());
        
        $('#'+sid).text($(this).text());
        $('#'+sid).val(val);
        //alert(raw+" | "+val);
        if(sid == "pla"){ alert(val); }
        if(sid == "yea"){ 
            //$('#sit').text();
            //alert(raw+" | "+val+" | "+$('#sit').text()+" | "+$('#rep').text());

            runQuery(sid, val);
        }
        
        //alert('rep value: '+$('#rep').val());
        
    }) 

    $('#run').click(function(){ 
        runQuery();;
    })
});

function stripId(x){
    //alert(x);
    var id = x.substring(0,3);
    var vl = x.substring(4,x.length);
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = vl;
    if(id != "end"){ runQuery(id, vl); }
}

function runQuery(id, val){
    //var drtn = $('#rep').text();
    var site = $('#sit').text();
    var year = $('#yea').text();
    var plfm = $('#pla').text();
    var stwk = $('#str').text();
    var edwk = $('#end').text();

    if(id == "yea"){ var rslt = "platform"; var page = "tester"; }
    else if(id == "pla"){ var rslt = "strweek"; var page = "week"; var slct = 0; }
    else if(id == "str"){ var rslt = "endweek"; var page = "week"; var slct = 1; }
    else { var rslt = "resultDiv"; var page = "Weekly/result"; }

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    }
    
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById(rslt).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    //alert(rslt);
    //document.getElementById(rslt).innerHTML = '<div id="inResult"><img id="loading" src="/web/tools/_frontend/preloaders/Squares_3.gif"></img>Loading...</div>';
    if(page == "Weekly/result"){ document.getElementById(rslt).innerHTML = '<div id=inResultDiv><img src="/web/tools/_frontend/preloaders/Squares_3.gif" height="75" width="75" alt="Loading..."/><br>Loading..</div>'; }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", page+".php?site="+site+"&year="+year+"&plfm="+plfm+"&slct="+slct+"&stwk="+stwk+"&edwk="+edwk, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to get the .val() of $('.content') clicked, the returned value is "" (empty string).

Change your code to: `var raw = $(this).attr('value');`
And it will work.

PD: you will need to do so, for each tag element.